# Does every SE site have different guidelines for "questionable content"?

Tags: discussion, chat, flags

While I am aware that every single SE site must enforce and follow the CoC guidelines, and the fact that each site has slightly different site-specific rules to suit their needs, I have been wondering something for a while. Does every SE site have different guidelines for questionable content too? I asked this because, ever since joining the Anime/Manga SE site, I've seen a lot of questionable messages AND images in the [Anime/Manga SE chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/6697).

To the point that I was wondering if I should flag said messages and get a moderator to see this, because even though the chat is dedicated to anime and manga, there's a clear distinction between that and ecchi/hentai. And yes, many anime/manga tend to blur that line and that makes moderating a site/chat like that even more difficult, but even so, content like that is sure to get you suspended from other sites and their chats, and not just because it was off-topic.

So my question is very simple, do we have different guidelines for stuff like this? Should a site such as that have stricter guidelines for the issues mentioned above? And should I (or any other user) flag for moderator attention if we see content such as that?

Comment: Related: [Is this type of content 'inappropriate content' for the chat?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/331240/241919). Anime.SE mod here. Note that while I'm not particularly active on chat, I do monitor the chat room and AFAIK there's no content that crossed the hentai/explicit line, yet.

Comment: See also (possibly duplicates): [Can we standardise chat moderation policies?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/267365/can-we-standardise-chat-moderation-policies); [Allow chat rooms to define their own rules within limits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/267383/allow-chat-rooms-to-define-their-own-rules-within-limits); [Regarding Stack Exchange-wide chat moderation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/112691/regarding-stack-exchange-wide-chat-moderation); [Toward a philosophy of Chat](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/270587/toward-a-philosophy-of-chat)

Comment: Such content will get you suspended from sites meant for small kids. However, keep in mind SE is behind "You must be 13 y/o to take part" wall so there is no risk kids will be exposed to this "bad stuff".

Comment: What was the nature of the questionable content?

Comment: @ShadowWizardChasingStars "keep in mind SE is behind "You must be 13 y/o to take part" — that's not exactly relevant. As I was made aware by [Shog9's post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/270587/908360), chat transcripts are wildly public: "You can't control who reads what you write in chat: transcripts are completely public, open to anyone, even people who aren't visible in chat, even people who aren't members of the main Q&A site." I seem to conclude that everyone in the world with an internet connection can be exposed to what gets posted in SE chatrooms.

Comment: @This_is_NOT_a_forum [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qb71R.jpg). No nudity, but mildly sexual.

Comment: Kissing is a long way from "sexual", even mildly sexual. I assume you are more a fan of René Magritte's interpretation of *The Lovers*?

Comment: @MetaAndrewT: Perhaps it's not so much that particular images are beyond the pale as that the preponderance of certain themes lends a seedy aspect to the chat room.

Comment: @MetaAndrewT. Its as Monica said, the images themselves aren't directly out of some hentai, hopefull. But if you're familiar with a anime and manga (as an anime.se mod I hope you are), then it should be easy to see what kind of content those images are referring to. Especially some that involved animal characters kissing.

Comment: @ShadowWizardChasingStars: This kind of thing (example from a few days earlier) is further along the romantic-sexual axis, & the girls appear younger: https://i.stack.imgur.com/im23j.jpg.

Answer (score 14):

Generally, jumping into an unfamiliar chatroom and going on a flagging spree is considered unreasonable behavior. Of course, you can and should raise a flag if you see something that [shocks the conscience](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shocks_the_conscience). However, different sites and different rooms have their own local cultures. There are plenty of other rooms you can go to if a particular one doesn't have the content you're looking for.

Comment: I don't necessarily disagree, except I'm very familiar with the room, and its 'local culture' (I read a lot of manga myself). That's how I was able to tell that something isn't quite right. And again, I do know that different sites and chats have slightly different rules, but does that mean that we can let blatantly problematic content slide?

Comment: So... did you flag the content you considered blatantly problematic? I don't really understand the issue here. Your question sounded like you were wondering about a general policy; now, it sounds like you might be just coming here with an axe to grind, one where I don't know the context.